# Weird Java Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

Why am I getting a `NullPointerException`?? I instantiate the node object in the Board.setStartPosition. Then I call it from my driver using b.getStartPosition(). I have simplified my code to only leave relavant information.

Driver.java

```
Static Board b;

public static void main(String[] args){
     b = new Board(3,3);
     b.setStartPosition(1, 1);
     b.createPath(b.getStartPosition());
}
```

Board.java

```
public class Board {
    private int length;
    private int width;
    private Node[][] board;
    private ArrayList<Node> openList;
    private ArrayList<Node> closedList;
    private Node startPosition;
    private Node endPosition;

    Board(int length, int width){
        board = new Node[length][width];

        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int row=0; row < board.length; row++){
            for(int col=0; col < board[row].length; col++){

                int randomNum = rand.nextInt(10);

                if(randomNum == 0){
                    board[row][col] = new Node('X',row,col);
                }
                else{
                    board[row][col] = new Node('O',row,col);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Node getStartPosition() {
        return this.startPosition;
    }

    public void setStartPosition(int x, int y) {
        board[x][y].setStatus('S');
        board[x][y].setParent(null);
        startPosition = new Node('S', x, y);
        startPosition.setG(0);
    }

    public void createPath(Node n){

        //Continue until we cant find a path or we exhaust our searches

        //THIS IS WHERE I GET A NULLPOINTER. IT SEEMS TO THINK THAT MY NODE
        //n is null, eventhough when i pass it, i pass it by getting the startposition node
        //Add startPosition to closed list
        closedList.add(n);

        //Add things around start square to openList if applicable
        addToOpenList(n);       
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your stack trace? My guess is your `closedList` is not initialized

Comment: Where do you initialize `closedList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialized `closedList` or `openList`. Change

```
private ArrayList<Node> openList;
private ArrayList<Node> closedList;
```

to something like

```
private ArrayList<Node> openList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Node> closedList = new ArrayList<>();
```

*or*, better yet, I suggest you program to the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface. So really something like,

```
private List<Node> openList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Node> closedList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not instantiated your `openList` & `closedList`. You have just declared them :

```
private ArrayList<Node> openList;
private ArrayList<Node> closedList;
```

hence when you do this

```
        closedList.add(n);

        //Add things around start square to openList if applicable
        addToOpenList(n);
```

you will get `NullPointerException`.

You can initialise your lists as mentioned here at declaration:

```
 private ArrayList<Node> openList = new ArrayList<>();
 private ArrayList<Node> closedList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks . I should know this by know... I was debugging for like 30 minutes and could not figure it out. I figured it had to be something easy

Answer (score 1):

You never seem to set `closedList`. Why would you expect it NOT to be `null`?